# Coinciding the ideals in a semigroup

Tags: semigroups

Kindly, I am asking to light my mind by some leading hints:

> Can minimal and maximal ideals in a finite non-commutative semigroup $S$ coincide?

Thanks for the time!

Comment: Is your definition of non-commutative not-necessarily-commutative?

Comment: Hmmm you look familiar in someway, Resident Dementor?  And your profile looks awfully familiar!  8-)  It really is good to see you still around!

Comment: @amWhy: Oh yes! Thanks my friend. I am still Babak. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just consider ideals, every finite non-commutative group is a solution to your question. If you consider proper ideals, the minimal examples are the monoid $\{1, a, b\}$ with $aa = ba = a$ and $ab = bb = b$ and its dual version, the monoid $\{1, a, b\}$ with $aa = ab = a$ and $ba = bb = b$.

Comment: Thanks for your idea. Honestly, before asking this question, I had been thinking this question in an finite Archimedean semigroup. Do you think it is true in such that semigroup? Thanks again

Comment: No. Take the semigroup $\{a, a^2, a^3\}$ in which $a^3 = a^4$. Then $\{a^3\}$ is the unique minimal ideal, but $\{a^2, a^3\}$ is a proper maximal ideal.